# Getting an error "Caused by: java.lang.Exception: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983 throw err; ^Error: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'" #1121

Tags: node.js, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I am getting below error in android studio for "Sync Project with Gradle file"

Locations are as follows:

1. nodejs: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
   A). C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android
   B). C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-tools

2.Android Studio: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\

3.Android Studio Project: C:\Users\James\AndroidStudioProjects\Test-app\

4.Location for folders ".android",".AndroidStudio3.6" ,".gradle" ,"AndroidStudioProjects": C:\Users\James\

5.C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\

6.C:\Users\James\AndroidStudioProjects\Test-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android

7.C:\Users\James\AndroidStudioProjects\Test-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-tools

Versions:

1. System: Windows 10
2. npm -v : 6.14.4
3. node -v :v12.16.2
4. "version": "3.1.4" for C:\Users\James\AndroidStudioProjects\Test-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\package.json
   (Tried package.json with version 2.1 also but did't work.)

Error:

`Caused by: java.lang.Exception: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983 throw err; ^Error: Cannot find module 'react-native/cli'Require stack:- C:\Users\James\Test-app\android[eval] at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19) at require` `(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18) at [eval]:1:13 at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:20) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:38) at Object. ([eval]-wrapper:10:26) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30) at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25) { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ 'C:\Users\James\Test-app\android\[eval]' ]}`